# How to call characters from first list with second list

Tags: list, python-3.x, for-loop

I want to input two comma separated strings: the first a set of strings, the second a set of ranges and return substrings based on ranges, for example:

```
x=input("Input string to search: ")
search=x.split(',')
y=input("Input numbers to locate: ")
numbers=y.split(',')
```

I would then like to use the second list of ranges to print out specified characters from the first list.

An example:

```
Input string to search: abcdefffg,aabcdefghi,bbcccdefghi
Input numbers to locate: 1:2,2:3,5:9
```

I would like the output to look like this:

```
bc
bcd
defghi
```

Any suggestions?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where's your code so far, and where did you run into trouble?

Comment: The first number is the starting point, and the second number is how many characters to take?

Answer (score 0):

`split(':')` splits a "range" into its two components. `map(int, ...)` converts them to integers. `string[a:b]` takes characters at indices `a` through `b`.

`zip` is an easy way to read from two different lists combined.

Let me know if you have any other questions:

```
x = "abcdefffg,aabcdefghi,bbcccdefghi"
search = x.split(',')
y = "1:2,2:3,5:9"
numbers = y.split(',')

results = []
for string, rng in zip(search, numbers):
    start, how_many = map(int, rng.split(':'))
    results.append(string[start:start+how_many])

print(" ".join(results))

# Output:
# bc bcd defghi
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I've been struggling with this for a week now!